# Amazon Lex Bot - How to delete or rename a Slot

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex

I'm creating a new Bot with Amazon Lex.

I created and Intent, and a new Slot for it.

I now want to delete it or rename it, is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: On closer look at your image, you may be talking about `SlotTypes` instead of `Slots` and should probably edit your question's wording just to be clear. `SlotType` holds the values trained to fill `Slots`. You can create one `SlotType` and have it be used in multiple `Intents` by multiple `Slots`. The more specific `Slots` are only inside of `Intents` and give a name and prompts to that particular use of the general `SlotType`. I believe your question is actually "How to edit a SlotType name and delete a SlotType?"

Answer (score 2):

[image: Shows where to delete and edit slots]

To edit the slotName: left click on the colored slot name to begin editing.

To delete a slot: left click the circle with an X on the far right of the slot row.

Answer (score 1):

Jay have written answer on how to remove the slot from the current intent, however it will not delete that slot permanently, which means if you want to use it again it will use same old slot which you made.

To delete the slot permanently, got to **Slot types**

[image: lex-1]

then click on **Actions** and select **Delete**

[image]

This will permanently delete the slot from your console.

Comment: I gave a +1 and was about to change my answer to match your terminology. But actually, your answer is how to delete SlotTypes specifically, not Slots. Unless I misunderstand what you mean, I believe you are saying Slots when you actually mean SlotTypes. In fact, the OP may be making the same mistake in confusing the two....and is actually asking about SlotTypes! In which case your answer is the better fit.

Comment: @JayA.Little your comment makes sense.. in the pic put by OP, he is editing the Slot type, that's why i thought to put a separate answer to avoid any confusion.